# Why there are two hpyerlinks of Dash is running with new dash 2.9.3?

Tags: plotly-dash

I am using JupyterDash.

I just installed new Dash 2.9.3, then when I run below run_server, it created two hyperlinks. What are the difference between Dash is running and Dash app running as shown below? why there are 2 now? Thanks

```
if name == ‘main’:
app.run_server()

Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Dash app running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
```